# ¿Porqué no dispara la notificación de Pusher mi código PHP?

Tags: php, push-notification, push

Estoy usando una cuenta de Pusher.com para subscribir mi pagina web a determinados canales para recivir notificaciones, he usado el ejemplo que me indica la página 1 es el lado del cliente y otro es el lado del servidor. El lado del cliente he revisado y se conecta y subscribe al canal a la escucha del evento indicado. El tema esta en el servidor que supuestamente deberia disparar el evento pero no lo hace. Desde la misma página Pusher.com puedo probar enviando eventos y por lo menos pude comprobar que el codigo del cliente estaba bien pues recibia las notificaciones.

Este es el código que te indican a usar en PHP:

```
<?php
  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $options = array(
    'cluster' => 'us2',
    'encrypted' => true
  );
  $pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    '72b8c9ad15bdf336579c',
    'fc21a96e6e5374539b02',
    '426949',
    $options
  );

  $data['message'] = 'hello world';
  $pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', $data);
?>
```

Eso lo puse en un archivo llamado pusher.php y accedo a ella desde el navegador. Aclarar que ya habia instalado la libreria de pusher para php con composer y no dio error. Mi PHP es el 7.0 y al acceder a la url de este archivo desde el navegador, primero se demora un poco en cargar la página y segundo no lanza ninguna excepción. Uso Mozilla Firefox 52.4

¿Cuál seria el error, que estoy omitiendo? Please cualquier ayuda me vendria buena porque estoy comenzando a usar esta tecnologia y si ya en la plataforma web me esta dando problemas no quisera ver cuando salte para la móvil. Gracias

**EDICION 1**:

He dumpeado el resultado de la ejecución de la función $pusher->triger y deberia devolver un bool o un array en mi caso devuelve bool false. Imagino que hay un error. **Otro detallito que me faltaba por añadir mi conexión la hago a traves de un proxy tal vez ese sea el problema**. Por consiguiente he usado en las opciones lo siguiente:

```
$options = array(
    'cluster' => 'us2',
    'encrypted' => true,
    'curl_options' => array(
        CURLOPT_PROXY => 'http://ip_proxy:puerto',
        CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => 'usuario:clave'
    )
  );
```

pero nada todo sigue igual.

Código del lado del cliente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('72b8c9ad15bdf336579c', {
      cluster: 'us2',
      encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(data.message);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Te faltar especificar `my-channel` y `my-event`, podrías subir el código del lado del cliente, por favor.

Comment: Ese es el mismo nombre que le puse al canal y al evento para probar. Como ya habia puesto en la pregunta funciona disparando el evento desde la web de pusher.com. Ahora mismo te añado el código del lado del cliente